# Trouble upgrading gitlab from 4.0.1 to 6

Tags: gitlab

When upgrading my very old version of gitlab(4.0.1) to 6.0, after running the rails migrate script, the gitlabhq_production database just gets wiped out, leaving only tables, but no data in them. The command I am using is:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

I thought of checking out the upgrade scripts from every major revision and running them, but I figured this would be handled directly in the most recent script. Before running the above script, I also made sure I created a git user(both in db and on the OS), and reassigned table ownership to the git user.

Does anyone have any tips on how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to:

- restore your database (assuming you did a backup *before* attempting the migration)
- **[follow the migration guides](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/update)** from 4.2 to 5.0, and then from 5.0 to 5.X, then  6.0

The most recent scripts will be able to automate the upgrade process only from 6.x to 6.y.